# How to prevent the crashing of code in python due to writeTimeoutError?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I wrote a sample code to blink/dim the led based on the information send by python code to arduino as long as python is sending some information. The code runs fine to sometime, after some point of time, it suddently crashes and gives this error. What is this error and why this happens?

```
File "C:\PYTHON~1\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 261, in write
raise writeTimeoutError
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout'
```

Python code:

```
def glow_the_LED(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id,set_forbidden_list):
    if ((len(set_accepted_list &  set_list_new_id)) >0 & ((set_forbidden_list & set_accepted_list) == set())) :
        print"yes,bright the LED"
        use_LED(1)
    else:
        print"no,dim the LED"
        use_LED(0)
    set_for_comparison = set(set_accepted_list &  set_list_new_id)
    return set_for_comparison  

def establishing_connection():   #for establishing connection
    x = ser.read();
last_action = -1

def use_LED(activate):
    global last_action
    global serial
    if(last_action != activate):
        ser.write(activate)
        print "should open door -> " + str(activate)
    last_action = activate
```

Arduino code:

```
bool lastAction = true;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while(!Serial){}//wait until the serial port is connected
  Serial.write('1');
  pinMode(10 ,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial && Serial.available())
    handleData();
  }
  delay(50);
}

void handleData()
{
  char a = Serial.read();
     if(a == 'e')
     {  
       Serial.end();
     }
     else
     {
       digitalWrite(10,lastAction);
       lastAction =! lastAction;    
     }
  Serial.write('1');//ack
  Serial.flush();
}
```

I call all the function, set connection between with the arduino and python correctly. The code also works fine, but it crashes later with the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

George,  Without seeing any of your code, I'd suspect that you're sending data too fast.  This message can mean that the serial buffer is full, especially if you don't have any hardware handshaking enabled (common with Arduino serial setups).  Try pacing your writes with some delays, setting a `writeTimeout` or a higher baud rate.  Try also posting your code so we can help better.

Comment: i tried playing with the baud rate and set a writeTimeout. It's not helping.